# Clearer definition of a singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

"A point $z$ is said to be a singularity of the function $F(z)$ if in the complex plane there exists no circle with center at $z$ within which $F(z)$ is analytic."

Can someone describe this a little better to me? Just having trouble grasping the definition given above.

Comment: Your question isn't about fourier series. The tag should be removed and replaced with a more appropriate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definition says that a point $z_0$ is a singularity if the function $F$ isn't holomorphic in the point $z_0$.
Note that a complex function is holomorphic in $z_0$ if and only if it is analytic in this point.
For example you can take the function $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$. This function has a syngualrity in $z_0=0$.